# Create an Android Magazine Application using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am extremely new to Android and even new to app creation.
Now I have been assigned a task of creating a magazine application for Android.
The magazine may have videos, audios, images and other HTML5 elements. And I am told to complete this using Phonegap and HTML5. I have completed the HTML5 part and I am stuck. How do I wrap my HTML5 with the Phonegap framework? 
I went through the basic Phonegap apps and its website and I was able to find only the very basic stuff. How do I create my magazine with slide, pinch and other features.